# Python ctypes and DLL that uses a COM object

Tags: python, dll, com, ctypes

Under Windows, I'm trying to use a 3rd party DLL (`SomeLib.dll`) programmed in C++ from Python 2.7 using `ctypes`.
For some of its features, this library uses another COM DLL (`SomeCOMlib.dll`), which itself uses other DLL (`LibA.dll`).

*Please note that this isn't about using a COM DLL directly from Python, but it's about using a DLL that uses it from Python.*

To make the integration with Python easier, I've grouped the calls I want to use into my own functions in a new DLL (`MyLib.dll`), also programmed in C++, simply to make the calls from `ctypes` more convenient (using `extern "C"` and tailoring the functions for specific scenarios).
Essentially, my library exposes 2 functions: `doSomethingSimple()`, `doSomethingWithCOMobj()` (all returning `void`, no parameters).

The "effective" dependency hierarchy is as follows:

```
MyLib.dll
  SomeLib.dll
    SomeCOMlib.dll
      LibA.dll
```

I'm able to write a simple C++ console application (Visual C++) that uses `MyLib.dll` and makes those 2 consecutive calls without problem.

Using Python/ctypes, the first call works fine, but the call that makes use of COM throws a `WindowsError: [Error -529697949] Windows Error 0xE06D7363`.
From the rest of the library behaviour, I can see that the problem comes exactly where that COM call is made.

(The simple test C++ application also fails more or less at the same place if `LibA.dll` is missing, but I'm not sure if it's related.)

I've looked at the dependency hierarchy using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).
`SomeCOMlib.dll` isn't listed as a dependency of `SomeLib.dll`, although it's clearly required, and `LibA.dll` isn't listed as a dependency of `SomeCOMlib.dll`, although it's also clearly required at run time.

I'm running everything from the command line, from within the directory where these DLLs are (and the C++ sample executable works fine).
I've tried to force the PATH to include that directory, and I've also tried to copy the DLLs to various places where I guessed they might be picked up (`C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Python27\DLLs`), without success.
`SomeCOMlib.dll` was also registered with `regasm.exe`.

**What could cause this difference between using this DLL from a plain C++ application and from Python's `ctypes` when it comes to its own usage of the COM mechanism (and possibly the subsequent loading of other DLLs there)?**

**Which steps would give at least a bit more information than `Windows Error 0xE06D7363` from Python, to be able to investigate the problem further?**

The Python code looks like this:

```python
import ctypes
myDll = ctypes.WinDLL("MyLib.dll")
myDll.doSomethingSimple()
myDll.doSomethingWithCOMobj() # This statement throws the Windows Error
```

(The test C++ standalone application that works, linked to `MyLib.dll` makes exactly the same calls within `main`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like processexplorer to find out if all the required libraries are loaded into the running process.

1. Did you initialize the COM runtime somewhere in your Python code? In your C++ code?
   One difference between C++ code and Python/ctypes is that in the C++ code the dll's DllMain() function is called when the dll is loaded, Python/ctypes doesn't do this because of the fully dynamic loading of the dll.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not initialising the COM runtime anywhere in my Python or C++ code (at least not explicitly). Everything about this is done from within the 3rd party DLL and my own code doesn't know about any of it. Would some COM initialisation need to be done in the Python code too?

Comment: > Would some COM initialisation need to be done in the Python code too?

No, afaik.

At least if your code does run in the main thread.

Comment: These answers don't quite solve the problem, but they're useful to be on the right track. I'll accept this one, unless someone comes up with the exact solution later on...

Comment: How does one initialise a com object in ctypes? I'm kinda stuck trying to use [IFileOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065891/how-to-use-ifileoperation-from-ctypes)

Answer (score 5):

When you need an in-proc COM object, you don't link directly to the implementing DLL. You usually use [`CoCreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`CoCreateInstanceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680701(v=vs.85).aspx), which will load the DLL for you.

The lookup goes through the [application's manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx) and its dependant [assembly manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374219(v=vs.85).aspx). This is done to support [registration-free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375134(v=vs.85).aspx).

If there's no application manifest or if none of the dependant assembly manifests declare your class in a `comClass` XML element, the lookup defaults to the registry, which will check [`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691424(v=vs.85).aspx)<sup>1</sup> for a subkey named `{<your-CLSID>}`, itself with an [`InProcServer32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682390(v=vs.85).aspx) subkey stating the DLL.

This explains why SomeCOMlib.dll doesn't appear as a dependency. It doesn't explain why LibA.dll doesn't appear as a dependency of it, probably because it's dynamically loaded. If you profile your app within Dependency Walker, you'll see a log of LoadLibrary calls in the bottom pane. To profile it, open your Python executable in Dependency Walker, then go to menu option Profile->Start profiling..., set the parameters to run your `.py` file and click Ok.

The 0xE06D7363 exception code is a [Visual C++ exception code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185294). You should check the source code of `doSomethingWithCOMobj`. To debug it, use your preferred tool (Visual C++, WinDbg, etc.), open Python's executable, setting up the arguments to run your `.py` file, and enable a breakpoint on the first statement of the function before running the application. Then run it and step through each instruction.

It's really hard to guess what's different about your native C++ application and Python, but it may be that different COM initialization arguments are used by Python and `doSomethingWithCOMobj`, or that you haven't declared it `__stdcall` (although being a void function that shouldn't matter), or that it tries to write to stdout and you're using `pythonw.exe` which isn't a console application, etc.

---

<sup>1.</sup> `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a mix of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that neither my C++ application, nor my Python application do any COM initialisation. If something happens, it's automatic (and visibly doesn't happen when Python is used). I'm merely using this 3rd-party DLL which uses that COM DLL.

Comment: @Bruno, that sounds odd. That may mean either that your C++ is actually calling `CoInitialize[Ex]`/`OleInitialize`, or that MyLib.dll or SomeLib.dll is doing it with `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED` (ther default of `CoInitialize` and `OleInitialize`) after your Python app called `CoInitializeEx` with `COINIT_MULTITHREADED`. I think DLLs shouldn't ever call these functions by themselves.

Comment: @Bruno, as for the actual error, since it looks like a C++ exception code, I'd look at and debug MyLib.dll. If you have Visual C++, you may debug a DLL by running an app that loads and uses it, such as your Python app.

Comment: Do you happen to know how this is done in ctypes? I'm [trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065891/how-to-use-ifileoperation-from-ctypes) to use IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) but not sure how to go about it

Comment: Look at the actual interface definition in shobjidl_core.h, since the method order in the documentation is alphabetic, and actual class/struct order matters. Pay special attention to out and in-out parameters. Shell objects expect to live in an STA (single-threaded apartment).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess that you have the [same issue that I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266538/ctypes-dll-call-works-in-ipython-but-not-in-regular-python), although I don't really know because unlike this case, I know nothing about the dll I am using.  6 years later I don't know if you can still test this, but I wonder if importing `pythoncom` would solve the problem.

```
import ctypes
import pythoncom
myDll = ctypes.WinDLL("MyLib.dll")
myDll.doSomethingSimple()
myDll.doSomethingWithCOMobj() # This statement throws the Windows Error
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, but I'm no longer in a position to try this. That seems like a reasonable solution.