# ctypes dll call works in ipython but not in regular python

Tags: python, windows, dll, ipython, ctypes

NOTE: My original question was closed for being off-topic, but I am resubmitting this with an answer for any who might run into a similar issue

---

My system details:

```
Windows 10 64-bit
Python 3.6 64-bit
```

I unfortunately cannot share data files or the dll due to confidentiality, but I am using a vendor provided dll (written in Delphi) to read binary instrument data files. I also do not have access to the source code, nor any entitlement to detailed coding support.

A sample script called filereadtest.py is shown below.

```
import ctypes 

binary_file = r"C:\path\to\binaryfile"
dll_file = r"C:\path\to\dll.dll"
dll = ctypes.WinDLL(dll_file)
dll.OpenDataFile.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p]
dll.OpenDataFile.restype = ctypes.c_int32
fhandle = dll.OpenDataFile(binary_file)
print(fhandle)
dll.CloseDataFile()
```

When called with ipython, this call is successful, but when called with regular python, this call gives an OSError:

```
>>> ipython filereadtest.py
0

>>> python filereadtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filereadtest.py", line 8, in <module>
    fhandle = dll.OpenDataFile(binary_file)
OSError: [WinError 250477278] Windows Error 0xeedfade
```

Comment: I remember running into exactly this scenario many years ago, and it took me hours to track it down. (I think the clue was that it also worked in the PyWin32 mini-IDE, but didn't work in IDLE.) I'm glad there's now a searchable answer for the next person who runs into it 5-10 years down the road. :)

Comment: @abarnert thanks for the comment. I was also in this rabbit hole for several hours and was hoping to spare someone else the pain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPython imports a lot of libraries, and buried deep within that import tree, a windows specific flag imports `win32com`, which in turn imports `pythoncom`.  The pythoncom import loads the library `pythoncomXX.dll`. (XX=36 or python version number).  In this case the dll depends upon this library being loaded.
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/pythoncom.html

The following script works:

```
import ctypes 
import pythoncom  # necessary for proper function of the dll

binary_file = r"C:\path\to\binaryfile"
dll_file = r"C:\path\to\dll.dll"
dll = ctypes.WinDLL(dll_file)
dll.OpenDataFile.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p]
dll.OpenDataFile.restype = ctypes.c_int32
fhandle = dll.OpenDataFile(binary_file)
print(fhandle)
dll.CloseDataFile()
```

Comment: @eryksun: Yeah, passing `str` to `wchar_t *` functions without argtypes does magically happen to work on narrow Unicode Windows builds of Python 3.0-3.4, but it's not correct in 2.x or 3.5+ (or wide Unicode 3.0-3.4), and it's not a good idea to rely on even where it does work.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for the comments, answer and question updated accordingly